# Mesh From Kinect point cloud

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, mesh, point-clouds

I am looking for a solution to create a mesh for unity from a point cloud (generated by a Kinect V1 sensor). I already gathered the colored point cloud

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: If you have the point cloud already, it means that is a file under some format. You need to convert or verify if that format is compatible with unity. if not converted to something like OBJ that should be automatically detected by unity as a 3d asset once you import it and use it as any other 3d object in unity.